# Python : use a class methods as static , when its implemented as instance methods

Tags: python, oop, static, instance, instance-variables

I have a big class which has a lot of functions and attributes.
the instances are created from data in a remote database.

the process of creating each instance is very long and heavy.

In performance sake ive created a bunch class from this heavy class.
so accessing the attributed is easy and works great .
the problem is how to use the methods from that class.

ex :

```
class clsA():
   def __init__(self,obj):
        self.attrA=obj.attrA
   def someFunc(self):
        print self
class bunchClsA(bunch):
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       # this is the problem:
       try:
            #try and return a func
            func = clsA.attr
            return func
       except:
            # return simple attribute 
            return self.attr
```

Clearly this dosent work , Is there a way i could access the instance function staticly  and override the "self" var ?

Comment: tnx , class . edited.

Comment: Whatever you are doing, this is a huge HACK that is far from a correct/good solution. But if you still insist binding the methods/functions of another class to `bunchClsA` instances then you can do that like this in `buncChlsA.__getattr__`: `return types.MethodType(vars(clsA)[attr], self)` This isn't a piece of code one could be proud of. If you use this up in your sources then I recommend disclaiming ownership of this "solution". I don't understand why is this better than writing the methods directly to `bunchClsA`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and what's the problem? How does it not work?

Comment: I know its a hack , and im trying not to duplicate all the methods (theres a lot.), thanks gor the idea.

Comment: Why aren't you using multiple inheritance?

Comment: if i could re design the "project"  i would. bit i cant.  any more ideas for this hack?

Comment: You can write `__getattr__` but you can't write `class bunchClsA(ClsA, bunch)`?

Comment: If i will inherit ClsA , i lost the point of this hack , cause ClsA is a vrewy heavy class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a nice solution to the problem :

```
from bunch import Bunch
import types
#Original class: 
class A():
  y=6
  def __init__(self,num):
    self.x=num
  def funcA(self):
    print self.x

#class that wraps A using Bunch(thats what i needed .. u can use another):
class B(Bunch):
  def __init__(self, data, cls):
    self._cls = cls # notice, not an instance just the class it self
    super(B, self).__init__(data)

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    # Handles normal Bunch, dict attributes
    if attr in self.keys():
      return self[attr]
    else:
      res = getattr(self._cls, attr)
      if isinstance(res, types.MethodType):
        # returns  the class func with self overriden
        return types.MethodType(res.im_func, self, type(self))
      else:
        # returns class attributes like y 
        return res

data = {'x': 3}
ins_b = B(data, A)
print ins_b.funcA() # returns 3
print ins_b.y # returns 6
```

And this solves my issue, its a hack and if you have the privileges, redesign the code.